# Jquery form validator error with file input: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble working with a file input and jquery form validator, without the validator, my code works just fine (also, without the file input, the validator works perfect) but once I try to mix them I keep getting a "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" error I just can't figure out, could anyone lend me a hand?

As additional information, the error is being thrown when it executed the form2.validate() function, before that, if any of my required fields (including the file) is missing, it works the way it should.

HTML code:

```
<form class="smart-form" id="massiveUpload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Cliente:</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-4">
                <label class="label">Número de Cliente</label> <label for="file"
                                class="input input-file">
                    <div class="button" id="clientsButton" name="clientsButton">
                        <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#search-clients-modal">Buscar
                    </div> <input type="text" name="clientNumber" id="clientNumber" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Número de Cliente" />
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-4">
                <input type="hidden" name="clientId" id="clientId"> 
                <label class="label">Nombre de Contacto</label> 
                <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="clientFullName" id="clientFullName"
                                readonly="readonly" placeholder="Nombre completo del cliente" />
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-4">
                <label class="label">Teléfono</label> <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" name="clientPhoneNumber" id="clientPhoneNumber" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Teléfono del cliente" />
                </label>
            </section>
            <section class="col col-4">
                <label class="label">RFC</label> 
                <label class="input"> <input type="text" name="clientRFC" id="clientRFC" readonly="readonly" placeholder="RFC del cliente" /></label>
            </section>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos Generales:</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <section class="col col-6">
                <label class="label">Almacén</label>
                    <label class="select">
                        <select name="warehouse" id="warehouse">
                            <option value="">Seleccione Almacén</option>                                        
                        </select> 
                    </label>
            </section>  
            <section class="col col-6">             
                <label class="label">Tipo de objeto</label>
                    <label class="select">
                        <select name="objectType" id="objectType" >
                            <option value="" >Tipo de objeto a realizar carga masiva</option>
                            <option value="PALLET" >Pallet</option>
                            <option value="ARCHIVO" >Archivo</option>
                            <option value="EXPEDIENTE" >Expediente</option>
                            <option value="EXTRAORDINARIO" >Tamaño Extraordinario</option>
                            <option value="ACTIVE FILE" >Active File</option>
                            <option value="CONTENEDOR DIGITAL">Contenedor Digital</option>
                            <option value="BOVEDA">Bóveda</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
            </section>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Archivo para carga Masiva:</legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="col col-6">
                        <input type="file" name="massiveFileUpload" id="massiveFileUpload"/>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <section>
            <button id="generateMassiveUploadBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="makeMassiveUpload()" title="Realizar carga masiva">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-up"></i>Realizar carga masiva
            </button>
        </section>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Jquery validator:

```
function makeMassiveUpload(){
    var form2 = $("#massiveUpload-form");
    form2.validate({
        rules : {
            clientNumber : {required : true},
            warehouse : {required : true},
            objectType : {required : true},
            massiveFileUpload: {required : true}
        },
        messages : {
            clientNumber : {required : "Seleccione un cliente"},
            warehouse : {required : "Seleccione un almacén"},
            objectType : {required : "Seleccione el tipo de objeto"},
            massiveFileUpload : {required : "seleccione un archivo"}
        }
    });
    if (form2.valid()) {
        //Do something

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an inline `onclick` handler that is calling your `makeMassiveUpload()` function.  Remove this `onclick` handler as it's completely unnecessary.

You should only put the `.validate()` method inside a DOM ready function since it's how the plugin is initialized.  In other words, the validation plugin is not even initialized until after your button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // <- DOM ready

    var form2 = $("#massiveUpload-form");
    form2.validate({  // <- initialize plugin on form
        rules : {
            clientNumber : {required : true},
            warehouse : {required : true},
            objectType : {required : true},
            massiveFileUpload: {required : true}
        },
        messages : {
            clientNumber : {required : "Seleccione un cliente"},
            warehouse : {required : "Seleccione un almacén"},
            objectType : {required : "Seleccione el tipo de objeto"},
            massiveFileUpload : {required : "seleccione un archivo"}
        }
    });

});
```

Now since the submit button is a `type="button"`, you must trigger validation programmatically on click.

```
$('#generateMassiveUploadBtn').on('click', function() { // <- capture click
    form2.valid();  // <- trigger validation on form
});
```

Alternatively, simply change this button into a `type="submit"`.

```
<button id="generateMassiveUploadBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" title="Realizar carga masiva">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-up"></i>Realizar carga masiva
</button>
```

<s>I don't know why all of your fields contain the `readonly` attribute.  How is the user supposed to interact with this form and fix validation errors if they cannot enter any data?</s>

Otherwise, I see nothing in the code that you've posted that would cause the error you describe.

**Working DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/v17bvjk8/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/v17bvjk8/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to make the validation programmatically because there's additional data I need to transform before executing my POST function. Also the readonly attribues is there because those fields are filled when selecting information from a modal, so to change them they have to select something else on that modal.

Comment: @Omaruchan, see edited answer that programmatically triggers validation from a `type="button"`.